# Add JSON values from two different files into a single file

Tags: javascript, json

I just need to merge two files with the same list, but with different values on each file. Preferably in JavaScript

For example:

File 1

```
{"list1":{"a":1,"b":2}
{"list2":{"c":3,"d":4}
```

File 2

```
{"list1":{"a":5,"b":6}
{"list2":{"c":7,"d":8}
```

The desired result is

```
{"list1":{"a":6,"b":8}
{"list2":{"c":10,"d":12}
```

Sorry for the noob question, but the person who sent me the files should have done this themselves, but are currently unavailable. The files are too big to do by hand.

Comment: what language do you prefer to do this in?

Comment: I have a few questions: I see two files with two lists each. Not one list. What if list2 also contains "a"? Should those list be kept seperate? like `{"list1":{"a":6,"b":8}
{"list2":{"a":4,"c":10,"d":12}`?

Comment: Yes they should remain separate.But if there's no solution I could split the lists into their own files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not very flexible code, but it would be far more work, to make something more dynamic. You would have to parse the objects recursevely and check if the property is an object and then jump deeper. Until ou find the values.

And please be aware that I'm not making any type checking whatsoever. If the data contains faulty data it is not cought properly. Also this code requires this exact structure. If your object contains other properties it might crash too.

```js
// your data
const f1l1 = '{"list1":{"a":1,"b":2}}';
const f1l2 = '{"list2":{"c":3,"d":4}}';
const f2l1 = '{"list1":{"a":5,"b":6}}';
const f2l2 = '{"list2":{"c":7,"d":8}}';

var result1= JSON.parse(f1l1);
var result2= JSON.parse(f1l2);

//the names of the list as they appear in your real data *must* be the first object
const nameList1 = Object.keys(result1)[0];
const nameList2 = Object.keys(result2)[0];

//remove the list name
result1=result1[nameList1];
result2= result2[nameList2];

//get data from other file nd remove list name
const file2List1= JSON.parse(f2l1)[nameList1];
const file2List2= JSON.parse(f2l2)[nameList2];

// go through all items and sum them if the value is already in the list, else put it in for list1
for (var prop in file2List1) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(file2List1, prop)) {
        if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(result1, prop)){
          result1[prop] = result1[prop] + file2List1[prop];
        }else{
          result1[prop] = file2List1[prop];
        }
    }
}
// and now for list2
for (var prop in file2List2) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(file2List2, prop)) {
        if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(result2, prop)){
          result2[prop] = result2[prop] + file2List2[prop];
        }else{
          result2[prop] = file2List2[prop];
        }
    }
}
//put names of lists back in.
result1 = {[nameList1]:result1};
result2 = {[nameList2]:result2};

//check results:
console.log("input data:");
console.log(JSON.parse(f1l1));
console.log(JSON.parse(f1l2));
console.log(JSON.parse(f2l1));
console.log(JSON.parse(f2l2));

console.log("output data:");
console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out

```
newList = list1.concat(list2);
```

Comment: It's not an array. Plus he want's to add the values it would require a non native function